# How to solve twitteR Package, Unrecognized CURL options: date

Tags: r, twitter, curl, rcurl

I'm using twitteR packages (and all needed packages), which are all latest version to do "Lynas Malaysia" twitter sentiment analysis.

The [source code](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/kaichew/blog/who-is-tweeting-about-you-at-the-period/) is as below:

```
library(twitteR)
library(plotrix)

dontshowtweet <- 0
showtweetyesterday <- searchTwitter("lynas", n=1000, 
                                    date=as.character(Sys.Date()-7))
sources <- sapply(showtweetyesterday, function(x) x$getScreenName())
sources <- gsub("</a>", "", sources)
sources <- strsplit(sources, ">")
sources <- sapply(sources, function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 1, x[2], x[1]))

pie(table(sources),
    main = "Who is tweeting about me")
length(showtweetyesterday)

df <- twListToDF(showtweetyesterday)
df[1:1000,c(10,4)] #screen name & created date
length(showtweetyesterday)
```

I still faced error, caused by RCurl. By using warnings(), I got:

```
In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
Unrecognized CURL options: date
```

How to solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Josh O'Brien for editing :)

Comment: No problem. If you haven't already, you can look at how I got the code blocks by clicking on the 'edit' button for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, the `searchTwitter` function has no `date` argument: you probably want `since` instead.